# How to format UITextField.ReplaceText

Tags: c#, xamarin

The method

```
UITextField.ReplaceText(range, string);
```

Takes a UITextRange **range**. How do I format the range? The string is self-explanatory, but there is no documentation on how to go about forming the range.

I have tried

```
UITextRange range = new UITextRange(4, 1);
```

However, this gives me an error.

Comment: Well, when you write "gives me an error" - you should at least paste this error here. As I looked at Xamarin documentation, there is no such constructor that takes two ints - http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextRange/

Comment: Yes, you're right. The error was in regard to not allowing a constructor that takes two ints. So how do I go about formatting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITextRange range = myTextField.GetTextRange(start,end);
myTextField.ReplaceText(range, newstring);
```

Comment: they're just ints - the start and end index of the text you want to replace